# Is it possible to split a unit cube in such way?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to split a three-dimensional unit cube into $42$ tetrahedrons of equal volume with nonoverlapping interiors?  The two-dimesional case is discussed in ["On Dividing a Square into Triangles" by Paul Monsky, American Mathematical Monthly 77 :2 (1970), 161-164](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317329).

Addition: Is it possible for $44$ tetrahedrons instead of $42$ ones?

Comment: @ Willemien: Could you kindly give an exact reference? Sorry, I don't find your "No" in Wiki.

Comment: ono it is possible see Joffans answe, the problem i was comparing it with " you cannot split a tetrahadrons in similar tetrahadrons"

Comment: @ Willemien : If you don't delete your first comment...

Comment: @ Blue : Thank you for your edit. It's kind of you.

Comment: The Monsky article starts by asserting that a unit square cannot be divided into *an odd number* of non-overlapping triangles. The last line of the JSTOR preview teases a "more  general result" that falls on the next page; I hate when that happens! That result is (paraphrased slightly): *If the unit square is divided into $m$ non-overlapping triangles of (not-necessarily equal) areas, $a_i$, then there is a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients such that $f(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m) = 1/2$.* The proof is non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I believe so. It is possible to split a cube into [six equal-volume tetrahedra (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_tetrahedra), generated by three diagonal planes through the cube, and all of those are the full height of the cube. Therefore that dissection also applies to a flattened version of the cube scaled along one major axis (e.g. height), so we can divide the cube into seven slices, each $1\times 1\times \frac{1}{7}$, and six-dissect each slice.

Comment: @ Joffan :Are these slices tetrahedrons?

Comment: The slices are square cuboids, $1\times 1\times \frac{1}{7}$. Each slice should be dissectable into six tetrahedra.

Comment: @ Joffan : Can you kindly state that in detail? You wrote "Each slice should be dissectable into six tetrahedra".  Why are those six tetrahedra of equal volume?

Comment: @ Joffan : I got it. Vote up is mine. See the extended question.

Comment: @user64494 hmm, that's probably too hard for me. :-)